# Moq Verify() on a mocked HttpClientHandler can't access the Content object because it is disposed

Tags: c#, httpclient, moq

I'm doing a mock HttpClient so I can unit test my code. I want to check the Content that is being posted.

I've done this:

```
MockHttpMessageHandler =  new Mock<FakeHttpMessageHandler>() { CallBase = true };
HttpClient = new HttpClient(MockHttpMessageHandler.Object, false);
```

and

```
 MockHttpMessageHandler.Setup(c => c.Send(It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>())).Returns(new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            });
```

and

```
MockHttpMessageHandler.Verify(c => c.Send(It.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(
                m => m.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "text/xml" &&
                    m.Method == HttpMethod.Post &&
                    m.RequestUri.ToString() == "http://www.test.com/" &&
                    m.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result == "TestContent")));
```

This works fine except for the `Content` line. I get an error saying that the Content is Disposed.

I'm guessing this is because it's a stream.

Is there an elegant way to be able to test the Content? It would be nice to directly get access to the content because I can test for encoding problems as well.

Edit:

The HttpClient is dependency injected into a class that does this:

```
public class MyHttpSenderClass
{
    HttpClient _httpClient; // DI populates this

    //...

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ComposeAndsendHttpRequestMessage(string url, string payload, string mediaType, string method)
    {    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(method, new Uri(url));

        httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(payload);

        httpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mediaType);

        using (_httpClient)
        {
            // I want to test this httpRequestMessage is correct
            var responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

            return responseMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

The exception, for clarification:

System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Http.StringContent'.

This is on the `m.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` part, because the Content is disposed.

Comment: Use a callback to capture the passed request message. From there you can inspect and assert as needed.

Comment: Could you provide more context about the subject under test?

Comment: I've added the code that is running, it composes and sends a `HttpRequestMessage`. Could you explain what you mean about callback?

Comment: Ok right. The request message is most likely getting disposed when the client is disposed. The assertion will obviously be invoked well after the subject has been disposed.

Comment: You don't have to mock a fake HttpHandler. Just change its `Send` to return whatever you want it to. As for the error itself, it complains about the *response*, not the handler. The response is just a `new HttpResponseMessage{                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,}` without any other content. Does `FakeHttpMessageHandler` modify it in some way?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP is trying to verify content of the request

Comment: And indeed, a request or response  is always disposed once it's no longer needed. That's why we can't resend the same HttpRequestMessage when retrying, we have to make and send a new request

Comment: I'm guessing the only solution to this then is to mock the `HttpClient` itself and capture the send method, unless there's another clever solution

Comment: @Nkosi which was provided by the OP as a hard-coded object in the mock, without *any* data or headers. This will fail one way or another. This test isn't useful, if it works, it will verify *only* that `Send` returns the object specified in `Returns`. Unless the real work is done in some chained handlers inside `FakeHttpMessageHandler`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos understood.

Comment: @NibblyPig what are you trying to do here? This code is verifying the mocking framework itself, not the handler. The problem is that you try to use the same response over and over, instead of creating a *new* one each time, something that `Returns` does allow. Even then though, there won't be any Content or headers to verify, just the empty Response object

Comment: I suspect this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).s

Comment: I am testing that my method is composing a `HttpRequestMessage` correctly - that it has set the headers/media type, content, and url correctly. I'll later also test the correct certificate has been attached. In terms of XY, I have a method that composes a `HttpRequestMessage` which must have the correct headers/media type/content attached to it. I want to test it is doing that job correctly.

Comment: @NibblyPig you didn't post any method, only a `FakeMessageHandler` which, as the name suggests, is a mock of the real handler already

Comment: The method is at the bottom of my question, after I edited it. I'll put a method signature around it

Comment: @NibblyPig A bit off-topic, but why are you disposing of the client if it is being injected. Shouldn't the container be responsible for that?

Comment: Probably. It's my understanding you're supposed to reuse HttpClient so I was going to look into making it singleton or something.

Comment: Actually examining the Content in Visual Studio shows that there is a byte array matching my string content that is accessible, but Disposed is set to true. So you can probably extract it another way. It's stored in a private variable though, so you'd have to do something pretty nasty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this with the help of the other answers, by reading the Content in the message handler itself and storing it, then resetting the stream.

```
public class FakeHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{ 
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public virtual HttpResponseMessage Send(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Use Moq to overrite this method");
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        MemoryStream msInput = new MemoryStream();
        await request.Content.CopyToAsync(msInput);
        byte[] byteInput = msInput.ToArray();
        msInput.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        Content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteInput);

        return Send(request);
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will help someone else trying to read the Content when mocking a HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that the same response object is used for all calls. This won't work because HttpRequestMessage and HttpResponseMessage objects are disposed as soon as possible. The *same* problem would occur if the mock used the same DbConnection, DbContext, or any other disposable object that's disposed by the code being tested.

`Returns` can accept a lambda, not just a single object, so the problem can be solved by using :

```
.Returns(reqMsg=>new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            });
```

or

```
.Returns(_ =>new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            });
```

Comment: The problem lies on the `HttpRequestMessage` rather than the response. Honestly I am a bit confused as to why the `HttpRequestMessage.Content` is disposed, I would have expected the Http Handler to have to consume it.

Comment: @NibblyPig who is going to produce that request message? If you want to verify that `Send` was called with a request matching those properties, the request was created and disposed when the call to `Send` was made, long before `Verify` was called. If you split that single expression into separate lines, I suspect you'll see that the problem is `m.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`. You're trying to *use* the argument here instead of verifying it

Comment: @NibblyPig BTW you haven't posted the excepion or the code for FakeMessageHandler yet. The stack trace in the exception would show *where* the exception actually occured. Was it inside `ReadAsStringAsync` or somewhere else?

Comment: @NibblyPig besides, if you want to verify those headers are always there, why not do so *inside* FakeMessageHandler and just throw if they are wrong?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I have clarified now in my question. The problem is how do you verify the `Content`? Presumably you need to read it to check it matches what you want. But you can't because it's long gone... I see what you're saying, perhaps the FakeMessageHandler can convert the content to a string and store it for later verification?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ended up mocking `HttpClientFactory` using [Moq.Contrib.HttpClient](https://github.com/maxkagamine/Moq.Contrib.HttpClient). Using the library's extension methods I achieved basically the same thing - copy the content before it gets disposed. Pasting here, as I found this as a bit leaner way, also we can do all kinds of other assertions.

Using `SetupRequest(Predicate<HttpRequestMessage>)` extension overload, to copy the HttpRequestMessgae content:

```cs
public class TestClass {

    // the place where we keep the content, after it gets disposed
    static string _actualRequestStringContent;

    private static bool MatchRequestBody(HttpRequestMessage r)
    {
        return _actualRequestStringContent == JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TheTestExpectedPayload);
    }

    public void Test() 
    {
        // Arrange: 
        HttpMessageHandlerMock.SetupRequest(async request =>  {

            // whatever the request,
            // copy its body before it gets disposed, for later asserting
            _actualRequestStringContent = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return true;
         })
         .ReturnsAsync(() => new HttpResponseMessage() {
              Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TheTestExpectedPayload))
         });
         Action verifyRequestBody = () => HttpMessageHandlerMock.VerifyRequest(
                MatchRequestBody, Times.Exactly(1), "Body did not match the expected body!");

         // Act...

         // Assert:
         verifyRequestBody.Should().NotThrow("Request body should be taken properly");
    }
```